# php/mySQL How do I get all the tags from the database for multiple items?

Tags: php, mysql, tags

I have 3 tables that look like this -

- content

  - cid
  - data
- contenttags

  - cid
  - tid
- tags

  - tid
  - tag

I'm trying to select 5 items from the content table whilst display every tag associated with the content. Here's what I have -

`SELECT c.*, t.tag FROM content AS c LEFT JOIN contenttags AS ct ON c.cid = ct.cid LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON ct.tid = t.tid LIMIT 5`

But all I seem to get is a whole lot of duplicate rows with the only difference being the tag. I thought ideally, all the tags could be merged in sql into one field? I dunno, am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function, which will return the tags comma delimited:

```
SELECT c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag) AS Tags
FROM content AS c 
  LEFT JOIN contenttags AS ct ON c.cid = ct.cid 
  LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON ct.tid = t.tid 
GROUP BY c.cid 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: oh wow, that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! But why does it exclude those entries which don't have any tags?

Comment: It shouldn't excludes them from the *resultset* since you are using `LEFT` joins. If you do not want it to return `NULL`, Try surrounding it with a `IFNULL()` ie `IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(...),'') AS Tags`.